# How can I mount a disk image?

Tags: linux, partitioning, mount, dd

I have a disk image `myimage.disk` which contains the partition table and a primary partition (i.e. a FAT32 filesystem). Think that as a USB pen image.

I want to mount the primary partition to a local directory. I know how to mount a partition image using the loop utils but here I have disk image. My guess is that I have to mount the image "skipping" the partition table but how can I do that?

Comment: See also http://superuser.com/questions/117136/how-can-i-mount-a-partition-from-dd-created-image-of-a-block-device-e-g-hdd-u
You may want to use simply `losetup --partscan --find --show disk.img` followed by `mount /dev/loop0p1 /mnt/disk`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mounting a multi-partition disk image in Linux](https://superuser.com/questions/211338/mounting-a-multi-partition-disk-image-in-linux)

Answer (score 58, accepted):

The kpartx tool makes this easier.  It creates loop devices in /dev/mapper for each partition in your image.  Then you can mount the loop device that corresponds with your desired partition without having to calculate the offset manually.

For example, to mount the first partition of the disk image:

```
kpartx -a -v myimage.disk
mount /dev/mapper/loop0p1 /mnt/myimage
```

When you're done with the image, remove the loop devices:

```
umount /mnt/myimage
kpartx -d -v myimage.disk
```

---

Alternatively, if you have a recent kernel, and pass loop.max_part=63 on boot (if loop is built-in) or to modprobe (if loop is a module), then you can do it this way:

```
losetup /dev/loop0 myimage.disk
partprobe /dev/loop0             # Re-read partition table if /dev/loop0 was used with a different image before
mount /dev/loop0p1 /mnt/myimage
```

When you're done with the loop:

```
losetup -d /dev/loop0
```

Comment: You don't need the `-o loop` above, `/dev/mapper/loop0p1` is already a block device (a mapper device on top of a loop device, you don't want another layer of loop device on top of that).

Comment: If you don't get partition devices (`/dev/loop0p1` etc.) after running `losetup`, run `partprobe /dev/loop0`.

Comment: `kpartx` seems to be installed by default in Linux Mint 18.

Answer (score 6):

Found this:

http://www.andremiller.net/content/mounting-hard-disk-image-including-partitions-using-linux

which seems exactly what I was looking for.

Here's the key part:

```
mount -o loop,ro,offset=32256 hda.img /mnt/rabbit
```

where the value of offset is in bytes. The suggested way to get the offset is to point `parted` at the image, then unit B for bytes and take the start value from the print output. As an alternative, assuming you have the disk space, do the obvious: once you have the offset and size, just use `dd` to extract each partition to a separate file.

Comment: For writing a really great answer, could you explain the most important parts here? Having a link is great, but having the info here would be best.

Comment: Here's the key part: `mount -o loop,ro,offset=32256 hda.img /mnt/rabbit`, where the value of `offset` is in bytes. The suggested way to get the offset is to point parted at the image, then `unit` `B` for bytes and take the `start` value from the `print` output. As an alternative, assuming you have the disk space, do the obvious: once you have the offset and size, just use `dd` to extract each partition to a separate file.

Comment: Yes, sorry for being too short. As Michael pointed out the relevent part is, of course, the `mount` line containing the `offset` option.

Answer (score 6):

Nowadays you can minimize your work by using `udisks`. Solution from [ArchWiki: udisks - Mount loop devices](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/udisks#Mount_loop_devices)

> To easily mount ISO images, use the following command:
>
> ```
> udisksctl loop-setup -r -f image.iso
> ```
>
> This will create a loop device and show the ISO image ready to mount.
>   Once unmounted, the loop device will be terminated by udev.

`-r` there for read only option.

Answer (score 2):

```
local_image_file=/var/tmp/image.img
first_byte=$(parted -m ${local_image_file} unit B print | grep Linux | cut --fields 2 --delimiter ':' | sed 's/.$//')
loop_file=/var/tmp/loop
mkdir -p ${loop_file}
mount -o loop,ro,offset=${first_byte} ${local_image_file} ${loop_file}
```

Comment: While this may answer the question, it would be a better answer if you could provide some explanation **why** it does so.

Answer (score 0):

I created a tool, called [**vDisc**](https://gitlab.com/es20490446e/vDisc), that makes it super intuitive.

From the **terminal**:

```
vDisc [file]
```

From the **file manager**:

[image]